# Using returned SELECT info in mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

In a MySQL database I have two tables linked in a join. One table contains `people details` and another `book details`. I want to search the databases for a particular author (`principalWriter`) and return all the co-authers (`additionalWriters`) they have worked with.

So I use

```
SELECT 
  books.additionalWriters, 
  people.name
FROM
  books
  INNER JOIN people ON books.principalWriter = people.personID 
WHERE personID = 1;
```

And this returns each book the author has worked on with the additional writers ID.

However how can I then use these returned IDs to look up their respective names in the name table? Is there a single query I can do to accomplish this?

Comment: What does `additionalWriters` return? One ID or a comma delimited list of ID's? What is the structure of your `name` table?

Comment: It seems your table is not in 1NF

Comment: additionalWriters returns a number of IDs delimited by spaces. I should have been more clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is not the query itself but rather the database design. You should have this tables:

- `Writers(*ID*, name)`: Will store all writers (principal or not)
- `Books(*ID*, name)`: Will store all books
- `Writers_Books(*WriterID*, *BookID*, Principal)`: This will store the relationship between the writers and the books and will specify if the writer for that book is principal or not

*Primary keys are surrounded by asterisks*

Note: You could also remove the Principal field and add it to the `Books` table, but if a book happens to have to principal writers, you won't be able to solve that with that schema.

Once you update your design, the query will be much easier.

Answer (score 1):

you need to join it again to peoples table. try this:

```
SELECT a.AdditionalWriters, c.name, b.name
FROM books a INNER JOIN people b ON
        a.PrincipalWriter = b.personID
     INNER JOIN people c ON a.additionalWriters = c.PersonID
WHERE   b.PersonID = 1
```

Comment: This is close except it returns only the first name of the additional writer along with the IDs. Each book has a number of additional writers. I should have been more clear. EDIT: commented above

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
SELECT people.name FROM people WHERE personID in 
(SELECT 
  books.additionalWriters, 
FROM
  books
INNER JOIN people ON books.principalWriter = people.personID 
WHERE personID = 1);
```